# "Repeated InvalidArgument: 400 API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key" Error When Using Google Generative Language API in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, error-handling, api-key

**Issue:**
I am encountering a persistent issue while using the Google Generative Language API in Python. The error message indicates an "InvalidArgument: 400 API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key." I have included a snippet of the error log below:

```
Retrying langchain.llms.google_palm.generate_with_retry.<locals>._generate_with_retry in 2.0 seconds as it raised InvalidArgument: 400 API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. [reason: "API_KEY_INVALID"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "generativelanguage.googleapis.com"
}
].
...

*
```

*Details:**

```
`
Language Model Used: llm
Code Snippet:
poem = llm("Write a 4 line poem of my love for samosa")`
```

**Additional Information:**

The error seems to occur during API key validation for the Generative Language API.
I am unsure why the API key is being flagged as invalid, as it appears to be properly formatted.
I have retried the operation multiple times with increasing delay, but the issue persists.

**Request:**
I would appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this issue. Has anyone else experienced a similar problem with the Google Generative Language API, and if so, how was it resolved? Additionally, is there a recommended troubleshooting process for API key validation errors in this context?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

In the provided Stack Overflow query, I mentioned encountering a persistent issue with the Google Generative Language API in Python, specifically related to the validation of the API key. However, I did not provide information about specific troubleshooting steps or attempted solutions.

To enhance the query, you may want to include details about any actions you have taken to address the issue. For example:

---

**What I've Tried:**

- Ensured that the API key is correctly formatted and includes the necessary permissions for the Generative Language API.
- Checked the API key against the Google Cloud Console to verify its validity and associated services.
- Reviewed the documentation for the Google Generative Language API to ensure that the integration is implemented correctly.
- Attempted the API call with a new API key to rule out potential issues with the key itself.

**Expected Outcome:**
I expected the API key to be valid, and the Generative Language API call to execute without encountering the "InvalidArgument: 400 API key not valid" error. The goal is to successfully generate a poem using the provided language model (`llm`) without any authentication issues.

---

Including information about the specific steps you've taken and what you were expecting from those actions can provide more context for potential helpers on Stack Overflow. This additional detail can assist them in providing targeted and effective solutions to your problem.`your text`

Answer (score 0):

Below are possibilities for you to try:

**Solution 1:**

This is the easiest one.
**I created a new Gemini API key using a secondary Google account (that hasn't created a Gemini API key before)** and it worked. I guess it will for you too :)

**Solution 2:**

You can try creating a new API key using the same Google account (triggering the API error), then wait for say 15 minutes to 1 hour, or perhaps several hours and this might work for you.

I created a new API key in the culprit Google account but when I tried using it immediately after creation, it was not working. Fortunately, mine works hours later after creating it.

So go ahead and try yours too with a new API key.

**Solution 3:**

While signed in to your Google account (the one triggering the API errors), visit these pages:

- Click **[here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/generativelanguage.googleapis.com)** to visit the **first page**:

This is a Google Cloud page and it should look like the image below (after you've accepted any terms and conditions that may appear).
[image]

Now click on the manage button that appears on the page above.

This should lead you to a page that appears as below:
[image]

On the page above, click on the **create credentials** button on the top right corner of the page.

This will lead you to the page shown below:
[image]

On the page above, you will specify the API being used (select generative language API), then specify the data being accessed as Application data (since you aren't accessing user data), then click Next.

Now you'll be led to another page shown below:
[image]

I didn't bother to proceed forward from the page above as I was not sure how to create the service account details. However, I have two useful links that can guide you in doing the same: [link 1](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-create) and [link 2](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview)

**Solution 4:**

Another solution that I think might cut the cake is Clicking on the free trial $300 credit as seen at the top of the page in the previous screenshot - if all else fails.

Hope you find a way out through one of the four avenues I have explained above.

Thank you.